# What type of distriburtion?

Tags: statistics

A comparative study of responses to a questionnaire addressed to consumers, showed that the lifetime of televisions usually distributed with an average of 8.2 years and a standard deviation of 1.3 years.If the company desires to offer replacement warranty for 2% of the devices with the shortest "Lifetime" how long should a TV is guaranteed?
---What type of distribution should i use?-Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Tried with Normal Distribution but did not managed to solve the problem.

Comment: I know little about statistics, so I really cannot help you with this problem beyond suggesting how to get other people interested. But you should present what you tried even if you didn't succeed, in order that others can say what went wrong with it, and what you should do. That's how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the lifetime $Χ$ of televisions follows the normal distribution with parameters $μ=8.2$ and $σ=1.3$, in symbols $$X \sim \mathrm{N}(μ=8.2, σ=1.3)$$ then we need to calculate the [2nd percentile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) of the distribution of $X$, i.e. the point $x_{0.02}$ for which $$P(X \le x_{0.02})=0.02$$ Then using the formula $$x_p=μ+σz_p$$ where $z_p=z_{0.02}=-z_{0.98}=-2.05375$, we find that $$x_{0.02}=8.2+(1.3)(-2.05375)=5.53$$ Therefore, in order for the company to meet the desired restriction, a TV should be guaranteed for the first $5.53$ years (please check for mistakes in the calculations).

Note: The assumption of the normal distribution can be questioned, since it is not justified by the given data. I assumed it because it is usual in such problems and because you said that you tried it also.